# JPA, OneToMany and ManyToOne

Tags: java, sql, jpa, orm

I'm using JPA to query data from DB. I got:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "supporter_1")
public class Supporter{

    @Id
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supporter")
    List<SubSupporter> subSuporter= new ArrayList<SuBSupporter>();
```

And second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "supporter_2")
public class SubSupporter{

    @Id
    private Long id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supporter_1.id", nullable=false)
    Supporter supporter;
```

And when I'm trying to get all Supporters and reach them in loop for it's ok, but after trying access to subSupporter list I get an error:

```
[EL Warning]: 2016-07-12 11:29:45.282--ServerSession(180353207)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi-part identifier "supporter_1.id" could not be bound.
Error Code: 4104
Call: SELECT ID, coulmn_name, supporter_1.id FROM supporter_2 WHERE (supporter_1.id = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="subSupporter" referenceClass=SubSupporter sql="SELECT ID, coulmn_name, supporter_1.id FROM supporter_2 WHERE (supporter_1.id = ?)")
```

I see that Select statment is wrong and I don't know why.

PS I'm using eclipse link

Comment: Is this an existing database or is the database generated from the entities?

Comment: It's existing DB with data, no generation from entites.

Comment: if it is "existing DB" then post the schema definition, and explain whether you really do have a column called "supporter_1.id"

Comment: The name in the joincolumn annotation needs to be the name of the foreign key field in "supporter_2".

Answer (score 0):

you can not have a dot in the column Name `supporter_1.id`. Change it to `supporter_1_id`

Comment: Have you rebuild, and redeployes your application

Comment: Now I'm running it as Java SE app i main class for testing

Comment: You are sure that it is exactly the same error message

Comment: Now I get: Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'supporter_1_id'

Comment: @Iwnow after changing the Name you have to Change your table if it is not be done automaticaly by jpa

Comment: so I have to set supporter_1_id as column name in supporter_1 table insted od just 'id'?

Comment: @Iwnow supporter_1_id

Comment: Ok, I changed it, I also added @Column(name= "supporter_1_id"), to id, and now I'm getting: nternal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'coulmn_name'.